# hide HTML5 video using media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got a landing page with a fullscreen width & height video background. Everything works fine. However, when I try to hide the video on mobile resolution using media queries, it doesn't hide at all.

I've tried enclosing the video in a div, and setting that div to display none. Didn't work either.

Does anyone have any idea how I could hide a background video for mobile devices?

Here's the main code.

HTML:

```
<div id="video_bg">
    <video id="video_background" autoplay loop>   
        <source src="backgroundmovie.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="backgroundmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />  
    </video> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video_background {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  z-index: -1000; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #video_bg { display:none; }
    #video_background { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work (http://jsfiddle.net/8D9HF/). Where is the exakt problem? Maybe your mobile-device doesn't support Media-Queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {#video_bg:display:none !important;}` just to check weather it works or not.

**EDIT**

Or you can inherit the above tags and then do a `display:none;` like below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    div#video_bg video#video_background source {display:none;}
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why did you include `!important`?

Comment: !important overrides any other code that might be effecting #video_bg. Wich didn't work.

Comment: I just included to know weather in his CSS, if something is getting inherited that is protecting it from not displaying none.  - @phpNoOb

Comment: Just wondering... Why do you hide the source instead of the video? 